# X11 stop windows/supper key event from reaching the OS

Tags: events, x11, windows-key

I am making a program that locks my computer by creating a full-screen window and disabling all ways to unfocus the window. For that I need to programmatically disable/enable the Windows key:

[image]

Is there a way to catch and stop the windows key event from being passed on to the OS (Ubuntu 21.10) using `libX11`? From what I understand I am supposed to use `XGrabKey` but it only blocks `Alt-Tab`:

```py
XGrabKey(display, ANY_KEY, ANY_MODIFIER, window, False, GRAB_MODE_SYNC,
         GRAB_MODE_SYNC)
```

Also I don't want to disable the whole keyboard.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘passed to the OS’? And why this specific key?

Comment: @user3840170 If you press the windows key when using Ubuntu, a screen with all of open programs will appear. It also allows the user to switch to a different desktop. As I am making a program that is supposed to act as a lock for my computer, I don't want the key to be enabled when the program is running.

Comment: What if the user runs Xfce, in which arbitrary keyboard shortcuts can be bound to arbitrary actions?

Comment: @user3840170 I am making the program for personal use and only the windows key allows the user to escape the lock that I have now.

Comment: Are these any use? https://askubuntu.com/questions/105558/how-do-i-disable-the-super-key

Comment: @alani Sorry but none of them can be done programmatically. Also most of them require `sudo` which I would like to avoid is possible.

Comment: @TheLizzard the idea was that as this for personal use only, one option might be to keep the windows key disabled in your settings as a one-off operation if you don't need to use the key yourself, and then the question goes away. There's an activities menu at the top-left of the screen that you can click on to access the same thing when needed.

Comment: @alani I use the windows key quite regularly. That is why I asked for a programmatic solution.

Comment: It could depend upon your particular window manager

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Do you mean `libX11.so.6`? I am using the default Ubuntu installation.

Comment: No, I mean your [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager). With a little effort, you can configure another one (e.g. [GWM](https://github.com/mnsanghvi/gwm)...). With more efforts, you could write your own one. Read also [ICCCM](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/)